# Approver Comments not visible in List item

Tags: custom-list, approval-process

I have a Custom List where users can add new items and then moderators can approve or reject the items.

When I approve a list item the Approval Status and Approve Comments are visible in the list view but not in the list item form.

How can I make so that I can see the Approve Status and Approve Comments in the list item?

Comment: Do you have content types enabled for the list?

Answer (score 1):

Create a column of type Single line of text or multi line and in the workflow body itself, set the value of the column you created to the WF comment field